# Object Claims to be Appended But Not Showing Up in Viewport

Tags: objects, append, object-mode

The title is pretty self-explanatory.  When I append the object, the data seems to come through but it isn't showing up in the viewport.  The original object was an imported .fbx if that makes any difference.  The object is a TV Stand and it should show up where the 3D cursor is.  You can see it highlighted in the outliner.  Any thoughts?[image]

Comment: select it in the outliner, move the cursor to the 3D viewport and pres numpad period so that the view moves to the object. If the object is too small or too large you might need to adjust the clip distance for the viewport.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks man.  It imported like a million miles away from my scene even though my 3D cursor was there.  Would that just maybe have to do with the origin of the object in the original file or something?  Thanks @cegaton